# Cannot find module 'react-i18next'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-i18next

This is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

 function MyComponent() {
  const { t, i18n } = useTranslation();

  return <p>{t('my translated text')}</p>
}


export default MyComponent;
```

I get the following error: **Cannot find module 'react-i18next'**.

Any ideas on how to fix it? Thank you!

Comment: either run `npm install react-i18next` or `yarn add react-i18next`

Comment: Are you sure you've installed the package in your root folder? (see: `https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next#installation`) How does your `package.json` file look? Can you see it there, under the `"dependencies"`?

Comment: fyi: a newer react-i18next guide can be found here: https://dev.to/adrai/how-to-properly-internationalize-a-react-application-using-i18next-3hdb/stats

Answer (score 8, accepted):

type in your console `npm install react-i18next`

you need to install the module